# Добавление информации из DataGridView1 в DataGridView2

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма подключенная к базе данных (Access). На ней Treeview при нажатии на ветвь в первый DataGridView загружается информация. Нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопу(добавить) из первого DataGridView выбранная строка c информацией о(группе товара,цена,наименование) добавлялась в другой DataGridView.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И как вы планируете это сделать? С какими конкретно проблемами столкнулись в процессе?

Comment: проблема в том,что не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Вешаете обработчик на кнопку, который вытягивает данные из второй таблицы и добавляет их в базу и в первую таблицу. Либо можно после добавления просто обновлять данные первой таблицы

Comment: скиньте пожалуйста какой-нибудь пример с кодом

Comment: Не держу у себя такое, но я почти уверен, что товарищ Гугл с удовольствием вам поможет.

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f878a041-1eb7-4978-bc4d-e50578fe6d7c/c-how-to-copy-a-selected-row-from-one-datagridview-to-another-datagridview-?forum=winforms